# Rails Custom Validation for Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have two models called Task and Employee, and they have many-to-many relationship.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
end
```

...

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end
```

I want a feature like this. An employee cannot have multiple tasks for the same period of time. Task model has start_date and duration fields, so I've required fields to make this validation.

```
@task = Task.create(start_date:Time.zone.now, duration:2)
@employee.tasks << @task
```

When I'm pushing a new task to an employee's tasks, I want to validate whether that employee has already a task conflicts with the new one. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, not the best but it should work. in the **Task** model, add a custom validation to check if other tasks for same **User** exists in define period.

```
class Task

validate :check_overlapping_tasks


def check_overlapping_tasks
  end_date = start_date + duration
        Task.where(user_id: user_id)
            .where.not(id: id)
            .where("(start_date BETWEEN ? AND ? ) OR  (DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL ? MINUTE)  BETWEEN ? AND ?)", start_date, end_date, duration, start_date, end_date)
   if overlapped_tasks.count > 0 
     errors.add(:base, 'User X has tasks in this period')
   end
 end

end
```